# Pandas- Find average based on multiple column value

Tags: python, pandas

Goal is to get average(integer) of `marks` column based on `name` value. If `id` and `name` column appears with exact same value more than once, then the `marks` with corresponding `name` will be considered once. For e.g. average of `x` = `(33+14+3)/3 = 16`

Sample dataframe:

```
   id name  marks
0   1   x   33
1   1   x   33
2   2   y   9
3   3   x   14
4   4   y   55
5   4   y   55
6   5   x   3
7   6   z   31
```

Expected output:

```
   id name marks avg
0   1   x   33  16
1   1   x   33  16
2   2   y   9   32
3   3   x   14  16
4   4   y   55  32
5   4   y   55  32
6   5   x   3   16
7   6   z   31  31
```

I tried:

```
df["avg"] = df.groupby("name")["marks"].mean()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute mean for each `name` after drop duplicates `(id, name)` and map result value on `name` column:

```
df['avg'] = df['name'].map(df.drop_duplicates(['id', 'name']).groupby('name')['marks'].mean())
print(df)

# Output:
   id name  marks        avg
0   1    x     33  16.666667
1   1    x     33  16.666667
2   2    y      9  32.000000
3   3    x     14  16.666667
4   4    y     55  32.000000
5   4    y     55  32.000000
6   5    x      3  16.666667
7   6    z     31  31.000000
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
df = df.set_index('name').assign(avg=df.drop_duplicates(['name', 'marks']).groupby('name')['marks'].mean()).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  name  id  marks        avg
0    x   1     33  16.666667
1    x   1     33  16.666667
2    y   2      9  32.000000
3    x   3     14  16.666667
4    y   4     55  32.000000
5    y   4     55  32.000000
6    x   5      3  16.666667
7    z   6     31  31.000000
```

If you need it rounded, chain `.astype(int)` to `.mean()`:

```
df = df.set_index('name').assign(avg=df.drop_duplicates(['name', 'marks']).groupby('name')['marks'].mean().astype(int)).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  name  id  marks  avg
0    x   1     33   16
1    x   1     33   16
2    y   2      9   32
3    x   3     14   16
4    y   4     55   32
5    y   4     55   32
6    x   5      3   16
7    z   6     31   31
```

Comment: Nice answer. Also, it's possible to simplify `df[~df.set_index(['name', 'marks']).index.duplicated()]` into `df.drop_duplicates(['name', 'marks'])`, and it still gets the same result.

Comment: Thank you @Nick. That simplification is neat - implemented! :)

Comment: For the next time, if you have to use `set_index` then `reset_index`, don't forget `map`. Check my answer. +1

Comment: Okay @Corralien, that's great advice. I'll remember! :)

Answer (score 1):

One option, which uses the same drop_duplicates idea, without using a groupby, is to pivot the deduplicated data:

```py
df.assign(avg = df.name.map(df.drop_duplicates().pivot('name', 'id', 'marks').mean(1)))
 
   id name  marks        avg
0   1    x     33  16.666667
1   1    x     33  16.666667
2   2    y      9  32.000000
3   3    x     14  16.666667
4   4    y     55  32.000000
5   4    y     55  32.000000
6   5    x      3  16.666667
7   6    z     31  31.000000
```